# want to show selected divs after form submission also

Tags: php, jquery

Bellow shown code does these things
when i select Scholership Programs from select list  the div element with class="mystaff_hide mystaff_opt1" will be shown
and then i select Family Income now div with class="mystaff_hide mystaff_opt2" will be shown. Now both are there on my window.
Up to this the code works fine

What i want is after submission of my form i want both of them are must be there on my window

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 pull-left">
        <div class="form-group">                            
          <legend>Options to Search</legend>
          <select class="form-control firstdropdown" name="sel_options" id="mystuff">
            <option>Select Options</option>
            <option value="opt1">Scholership Programs</option>
            <option value="opt2">Family Income</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 mystaff_hide mystaff_opt1">
      <div class="form-group">                          
        <label for="LS_name">Scholarship</label>
           <select  class="form-control" name="LS_name[]" id="LS_name" multiple="multiple">
         <option value="opt1">Scholership1</option>
            <option value="opt2">Scholership2</option>
        </select>
    </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 mystaff_hide mystaff_opt2">
      <div class="form-group">                          
        <label for="Family Income">Family Income</label>

        <select multiple class="form-control" name="FamilyIncome[]" id="FamilyIncome">
          <option value="opt1">Family Income1</option>
            <option value="opt2">Family Income2</option>
    </select>
    </div>              
    </div>
```

This is my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/js/jquery.multi-select.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.mystaff_hide').addClass('collapse');
        $('#mystuff').change(function(){
            var selector = '.mystaff_' + $(this).val();
            $(selector).collapse('show');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

After lot of search i got this code which is shows only recent related selected option's div

```
        <?php if(isset($_POST['sel_options']) && 
        !empty(isset($_POST['sel_options']))){
        ?>
        <script>
        var selected_option = "<?php echo $_POST['sel_options']; ?>";
        var selector = '.mystaff_' + selected_option;
            //show only element connected to selected option
            $(selector).collapse('show');
        </script>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Are you submitting form using Ajax?

Comment: No, After submit i am directing to same page

Comment: Better you case try with [`Ajax`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAzM2Qq6HUAhXIuY8KHbV7AjYQFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.ajax%2F&usg=AFQjCNET1WrVqP-BPFBEQY1R7V6crOtd1w&sig2=JP5YWkZ5Mr-WpBASz2YTbg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or [sessionstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store information about the state of webpage and read them after reload to restore the UI state

Example:

**Localstorage**

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

**Sessionstorage**

```
if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
} else {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " +
sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.";
```

Or you may want to use **[AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)**

> AJAX is the art of exchanging data with a server, and updating parts of a web page - without reloading the whole page.

As you are using jquery, you may want to look at [using Ajax in jquery.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: after lot of search i got this code which shows only resent selected option from the first select list and the related div will be present on the screen after form submission. I am attaching above that also please go through that and help me thank you.

Comment: I have added now please go through that

Comment: I think we have to store value of each selected options from first select list with id="mystuff" in a variable after for each value execute these lines using $.each function [  var selector = '.mystaff_' + selected_option;                     $(selector).collapse('show');

Comment: Your code is okay,  it should work now. Make sure you add the script tag in php at the end after dom is created.

Comment: Yes i have script at the end